# Does a tax increase on high incomes slow down economic growth?

Tags: economics, politics

The Republican party in the US has a position that that raising taxes on rich people leads to less growth. Is this true?

For one example of the claim, [CNN reported](http://www.cnn.com/2012/08/01/politics/house-taxes/index.html) in August 2012:

> Republicans seeking to shrink the size of government oppose any higher taxes and argue the Democratic plan of allowing rates to increase on higher-income Americans will stunt economic growth.

(see also [meta discussion regarding deleted answer](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1952/politically-motivated-deletion-of-answer) )

[Another example](http://www.forbes.com/sites/louiswoodhill/2012/08/22/economic-growth-will-pay-for-mitt-romneys-tax-cuts/) of the claim, from Forbes Magazine

> Economic Growth Will Pay For Mitt Romney's Tax Cuts

Comment: Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made. There are almost certainly caveats made: let's see what the politicians actually say.

Comment: @Oddthinking: It's not necessary, you've heard the claim many times, including this most recent vice-presidential debate. It's the exact opposite of the truth, as I explain in my answer. If someone has some data which supports this, or any theoretical argument why correcting this market imbalance should _decrease_ rather than _increase_ growth, please provide another answer. Otherwise, I will just accept mine.

Comment: Well, I think it depends on how high the tax is. An increase of 1 or 2% won't change much of anything. If the rate goes up to 90% however, then that'd certainly put me off joining a startup

Comment: @Casebash: Not clear at all if even 90% tax (collected efficiently) will dissuade anyone from anything. It was 95% under Eisnehower, and there were plenty of startups. I want to know theory and experiment, not opinions based on personal what-ifs. I have joined a startup, and taxes were the last thing on my mind.

Comment: @RonMaimon: It won't dissuade everyone, but it'll certainly dissuade a lot

Comment: @YannisRizos: If you are in the US and do not know this claim, or have not heard it repeated in every election since 1980, you have your head buried in the sand. But I added a link anyway.

Comment: I asked about the deletion here: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1952/politically-motivated-deletion-of-answer . I believe it is politically motivated.

Comment: @RonMaimon: it looks to me like your question is politically motivated. If you are happy with your unreferenced answer then what is the point of asking a question on this specific site? Ask it on any of the millions of forums about politics, that are done to discuss politics, not on a Q&A site that requires notable claims for questions and reputable sources for answers.

Comment: @nico: I am _not_ happy with my answer. It is theoretical, and I want more experimental data. It comes up in politics, but I am asking because I want to see the data. I asked an economist a few weeks ago, and he told me that you _can_ see a clear growth-suppression from high taxes in developing countries, and that people debate this endlessly. I wasn't sure about the data in other countries, developing or developed, my answer is based on the only thing I do understand--- free efficient market theory, and when it applies. I was hoping to get data and theory from the other side, if there is any.

Comment: @nico: In fact, originally my answer was part of the question, and the question only asked for opposing views. But the question got too long, so I just separated it into a short question and a separate answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This article](http://www.businessinsider.com/study-tax-cuts-dont-lead-to-growth-2012-9) presents a number of charts and data from the Congressional Research Service and other sources that indicates the answer is tax increases do not slow down economic growth, nor do tax cuts increase economic growth.

The nonpartisan Congressional Research Service [studied](http://www.taxwarriors.com/Portals/127975/docs/r42729_0917.pdf) this issue and released a report in September 2012.  The author examined individual income tax rates - both marginal and average rates - over the period from World War II to the present.  The maximum marginal tax rates range from 70 to 90 % in the 1945 - 1980 period, to today's 35%.  Capital gains tax rates were also evaluated, which are also substantially lower today than they have been historically.  Pre WWII data were not examined because few Americans were required to file federal tax returns prior to that time.

The tax rates were then correlated with economic growth data from the US Bureau of Economic Analysis.  Statistical analysis showed virtually no correlation between tax rates and economic growth.  If anything, there is a very slight increase in growth during periods of higher tax rates, though the author notes that this could be a result of other changes in the economy during the time period.

The study concludes:

> The results of the analysis suggest that changes over the past 65 years in the top marginal tax rate and the top capital gains tax rate do not appear correlated with economic growth. The reduction in the top tax rates appears to be uncorrelated with saving, investment, and productivity growth.

There is, however, a correlation to income distribution, with lower maximum tax rates leading to greater disparities in income, i.e. greater concentration of income at the very top of the economic scale.

Comment: Oh, ok, somebody else noticed. This data is unequivocal, it fits the theory I gave, it is bipartisan data, and I accept. I also note that in the model I presented, tax cuts on the wealthy hurt growth, because they prevent income redistribution. This is born out by the data. See meta for the text of the theory, which is censored here.

Comment: Can you find a better source than a newspaper article?

Comment: Mark: I suggest you read through the [original source](http://www.taxwarriors.com/Portals/127975/docs/r42729_0917.pdf) and briefly describe their methodology and extract some of the conclusions to address @Sklivvz's concerns.

Comment: This is a more detailed analysis, and less impartial, but in my opinion more accurate: http://www.businessinsider.com/history-of-tax-rates-2012-5?op=1